# queue with time stamped elements within a time period

Tags: java, data-structures, queue

I want to store in a queue, datastructure does not matter, only the elements that I have inserted within say last 5 minutes from current time. Anything older should get removed - so that any time I get the size of the queue it will give count of the objects inserted in last 5 minutes.

Basically all I have to know is how many times my app has made a http call to a sever in last 5 minutes before making the next call.

If anyone knows of some existing library that may have this implementation please share.

Comment: you forgot to mention things like: desired platform/language/etc...

Answer (score 8):

You can use a Priority Queue with timestamps as your keys.  So that when you call Peek() you always get the oldest timestamp still in the queue. Then each time you go to query for the number of items inside your window size: you cleanup the items outside your window and return the number of items still in the Priority queue.

For example:

```
public class CountInWindow {

    /**
     * Adding a main just for testing 
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("test started");
        CountInWindow test = new CountInWindow(5000); //5 seconds for testing
        test.debug = true;
        test.insertTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(100);//sleep 
        test.insertTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(100);//sleep 
        test.insertTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(100);//sleep 
        test.insertTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(5040);//sleep 5 secs
        test.insertTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        Thread.sleep(100);//sleep 
        test.insertTimeStamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(test.getWindowCount()); //Should be 2 not 6.
        System.out.println("test done");
    }

    java.util.PriorityQueue<Long> window;
    public static final long FIVE_MINS_IN_MS = 300000l;
    public final long WINDOW_SIZE;
    public boolean debug = false;

    //Constructor which defaults to 5mins
    public CountInWindow(){
        WINDOW_SIZE = FIVE_MINS_IN_MS;
        window = new java.util.PriorityQueue<Long>();
    }
    //Constructor for any size window
    public CountInWindow(long windowSize){
        WINDOW_SIZE = windowSize;
        window = new java.util.PriorityQueue<Long>();
    }
    /**
     * Add a new timestamp to the window's queue
     * @param ts
     */
    public void insertTimeStamp(long ts){
        window.add(ts);
    }
    /**
     * Clean up items outside the window size and then return the count of times still in the window.
     * @return A count of timestamps still inside the 5 mins window.
     */
    public int getWindowCount(){
        long currTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //Clean out old Timestamps
        while((currTime - window.peek().longValue()) > WINDOW_SIZE){
            long drop = window.remove().longValue();
            if(debug)System.out.println("dropping item:" + drop);
        }
        return window.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is priority queue really necessary in the scenario since the items are inserted on timestamp and it would be in order. Wouldn't just a queue interface be sufficient with queue.peek()?

Answer (score 5):

In what language? Is the queue persistent or in-memory?

If you need this behavior in Java, you can use a [DelayedQueue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.html), and have a separate thread calling `queue.take()` continuously in a tight loop to drain out expired items. `queue.size()` will then give you the size of remaining unexpired items in the queue. This requires that the items you put in the DelayedQueue implement the [Delayed](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Delayed.html) interface and return the value 5 minutes to the `.getDelay()` method.

Comment: Thanks, but the only problem with this approach is the thread will have to be running quite frequently to make the result best for the call `queue.size()`.

Comment: yes- it needs to be a tight loop (e.g. while queue.take() != null). Note that queue.take() will block until the queue has expired elements to be taken. The frequency of the iteration is then determined by how frequently items are placed on the queue (and therefore how frequently they become expired), and not so much a time-based garbage collection (so queue.size() will be precisely accurate at all times).

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize that queue.take() will block until the queue has expired elements to be taken. It will be interesting to know how they implemented DelayQueue - may be they use 2 queues internally one to hold the expired elements and one to hold the non-expired. Anyways thanks a lot - you people are so helpful - I feel like giving as a tankyou token a $25 visa gift card to you - not sure how to send

Comment: Haha- that will not be necessary! I try to give back a little bit in return for all the things I learn here.

Answer (score 0):

I have implement a `FadingLinkedList` like

```
public class FadingLinkedList<E> {

private transient Entry<E> header = new Entry<E>(null, null);

/**
 * ms
 */
private long livingTime;

/**
 * Constructs FadingLinkedList with elements of living time livingTime in
 * milliseconds
 */
public FadingLinkedList(long livingTime) {
    this.livingTime = livingTime;
}

/**
 * remove all faded elements,
 *
 * @return the count of not faded
 */
public synchronized int removeFaded() {
    long now = System.nanoTime();
    int count = 0;
    Entry<E> prev = header;// the last living Entry in the loop
    for (Entry<E> e = header.next; e != null; e = e.next) {
        if (TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(now - e.birthTime) >= livingTime) {
            // cut off this list here.
            prev.next = null;
            break;
        }
        count++;
        prev = e;
    }
    return count;
}

/**
 * Returns the number of elements that not faded.
 */
public int size() {
    return removeFaded();
}

public synchronized void push(E e) {
    Entry<E> newEntry = new Entry<E>(e, header.next);
    header.next = newEntry;
}

private static class Entry<E> {
    E element;
    Entry<E> next;
    long birthTime;

    Entry(E element, Entry<E> next) {
        this.element = element;
        this.next = next;
        this.birthTime = System.nanoTime();
    }
}

public synchronized void clear() {
    header.next = null;
}

public synchronized int getAndClear() {
    int size = size();
    clear();
    return size;
}
```

}