# In Golang, can I customise key comparison, if I am taking struct as key?

Tags: dictionary, go, hashtable

How does map in Golang compare keys? For some reason, I need to have a struct as a key, which has 2 values inside. I want map to compare by only first value, not second. Second is for my usage. Like in java, I can customise `equals` method, so map will take only `logically equal` keys within. Is there any way to do that?

Edit: Looks like there is no way to do that. So I am now putting down my problem here. Please help me to think in 'Go-way'.

So, I want to implement a 'timed map', which tracks the key insertion time. In other words, there is a map which accepts and processes the values. Now, if the data in map is older than some specific time-interval, then I should clear it out.

So, I thought of having a key struct which has id and timestamp. When a new key comes, map takes it with id and currentTimeInMillis. After sometime, if a key comes which already exists, then map should preserve the first insertion time and only updates the value array.

To process, I will have a looping over map and check if any particular key is inside for more than threshold limit, then I clear it out. I can have this timestamp in value array, but that also has a timestamp of its own, so putting one more might confuse someone else.

Please suggest something.

Comment: No, you can't change how the map hashes.

Comment: Oh, that's a bad news. I need to find some alternative. Golang is very 'limited'. :-(

Comment: @theGamblerRises Not limited. What do you want to do? Don't implement java code in golang.

Comment: Looks like only ID is a key, timestamp is a value and should be stored as value. I don't see any reason why you have to put both of them into a struct and use it as a map key

Comment: Yes, I am thinking in that direction. Looks like it might work for this case. But there could be some different scenarios in future. Thanks for the help. :-))

Comment: You could use a priority queue, too: http://stackoverflow.com/q/6644688/124319

Comment: @theGamblerRises, different scenario may be if you have some kind of composite key. But even in that case you can combine it into a single unique key by hashing the whole thing, joining strings, combining multiple integers into a bigger one etc. I don't remember any case in any language when that didn't work and I had to create complex key object with it's own comparison rules.

Comment: @creker What you describe (combining/joining...) is exactly what happens when you define a custom hash function (and equality) for a complex object.

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a Time Based Cache.  If so I would recommend having a look at https://github.com/patrickmn/go-cache to see if it fits your needs.

Comment: @coredump, I mean I don't remember when I had to use the object itself as a key. It's always some primitive value (string or integer) in some way or another. What I'm getting at is I don't find the ability to use complex objects as keys that useful. So Go's maps are not a limiting factor for me personally as I don't use that feature anyway.

Comment: You can iterate the keys and/or values of a map and compare them however you like but you can't modify how it calculates the hash for access operations.

Answer (score 0):

Put the time on your value. Here's some example of how to structure your data.

```
type DataObj struct {
     Id int
     Updated time.Date
     // other fields
}

m := map[int]DataObj{}
m[d.Id] = d // assign using the id as your key

for k, v := range m {
    if time.Since(v.Updated) > duration {
         delete(m, k) // remove the stale item
    }
}

// some logic like this for adding/overwriting
v, ok := m[newObj.Id]
if ok { // an element with this id existed
     if time.Since(v.Updated) > duration {
          m[v.Id] = newObj // assign new value over old one
     }
}
```

I can't provide anything much more specific because you don't have any code with which to work. It seems like you'd probably like some of this (like the remove bits) to run on a timer. To do that, invoke the function as a goroutine and use a timer so every X seconds it unblocks and removes items from the map. If you're doing this you also need to use a mutex so the calling scope doesn't access the map while the remove function running the background is filtering out old items.

The overwrite bit is really straight forward, just test if the item is in the map, check it's time stamp, if it's beyond the threshold assign the new value, if not do nothing.

The main thing to take away here is to not use a struct for your key... There is no reason to do object equality, your object has an id, us it as your key. Everything else you care about can be held on the value (even the key itself is). As someone pointed out this isn't Java and even if it were, equality overrides in C# and Java are literally a fucking nightmare.

Comment: Thanks for that. I am going with timestamp in values, now. I will update with my solution. Other than that, equality overrides in Java are very convenient for me. I like golang for it's simplicity and faster processing. But Java is so beautiful for me, ** personal views **.

Comment: @theGamblerRises yeah disliking overrides is just a matter of opinion. They can make code look nice but I think they make it harder to maintain in large projects and if you later on find you need to do reference compare it puts you in a pretty rough spot.